# Assign a Tag Multiple Triggers (Google Tag Manager)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've created a tag with all of my conversion code and I'm looking to have it populate based on multiple triggers. Is there a way to assign multiple triggers to the same tag?

I want to avoid having to create a separate tag for each trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that I had already configured a trigger on the tag. So in order to be able to add multiple triggers I had to delete the existing trigger. Then when you go to add a trigger back, it will present you with the option of multiple triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Tag existed, click Edit Trigger --> show pop up all of the trigger, tick on the check box of the trigger you want to add. Remember click on the check box, not directly on the trigger.